# Redux Query Dependent Mutations With Rollback Using createApi()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I have two mutations that need to happen one after another if the first one succeeds. As bonus I would like to undo the first mutation if the second fails.

I have the first part working but it feels clumsy and I'm wondering if there is better way.

Here is how I bring in my two mutations:

```
const [updateSubscription, {
    isLoading: isLoadingUpdateSubscription,
    isSuccess: isSuccessUpdatedSubscription,
    isError: isErrorUpdateSubscription,
    error: errorUpdateSubscription,
    reset: resetUpdateSubscription
}] = useUpdateSubscriptionMutation();
const [updateDeviceListing, {
    isLoading: isLoadingUpdateDeviceListing,
    isSuccess: isSuccessUpdatedDeviceListing,
    isError: isErrorUpdateDeviceListing,
    error: errorUpdateDeviceListing,
    reset: resetUpdateDeviceListing
}] = useUpdateDeviceListingMutation();
```

As part of a button click I run the first mutation where a subscription is updated:

```
const handleListIt = () => {
    if (deviceListing && subscriptions) {
        const updatedAvailableSeats = subscriptions[0].availableSeats - deviceListing.count;
        const updatedUsedSeats = subscriptions[0].usedSeats + deviceListing.count;

        updateSubscription({...subscriptions[0], availableSeats: updatedAvailableSeats, usedSeats: updatedUsedSeats});
    }
};
```

I then use useEffect() to check isSuccessUpdatedSubscription and run the second mutation:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccessUpdatedSubscription && deviceListing) {
        updateDeviceListing({...deviceListing, status: 'open'})
    }
    if (isSuccessUpdatedDeviceListing) {
        onClosed();
    }
}, [isSuccessUpdatedDeviceListing, isSuccessUpdatedSubscription, deviceListing, onClosed, updateDeviceListing]);
```

The same useEffect() is also used to check if the second mutation worked, isSuccessUpdatedDeviceListing, at which point onClosed() is called and the user is shown some different UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just handle both in `handleListIt`, there is really no good reason for the re-render with the useEffect. And then you can also handle the rollback as you want.

```js
const handleListIt = async () => {
    if (deviceListing && subscriptions) {
        const updatedAvailableSeats = subscriptions[0].availableSeats - deviceListing.count;
        const updatedUsedSeats = subscriptions[0].usedSeats + deviceListing.count;

        try {
          await updateSubscription({...subscriptions[0], availableSeats: updatedAvailableSeats, usedSeats: updatedUsedSeats}).unwrap();
          await updateDeviceListing({...deviceListing, status: 'open'}).unwrap()
       } catch (error) {
         // do your rollback
       }
    }
};
```